# Create new columns within loop or apply

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply

The dataset I'm working with is billing data by customer and month. In the end I'd like to make a dataframe that has customer IDs for rows and months for column names - as in the original data set. However, I'd like this new data set to contain dummy variables for whether the customer was "gained" that month aka. they had never been billed before and that month was the first time they were billed.

Here's a reproducible example as well as the loop I have written now:

```
set.seed(24)
example.data <- data.frame(
   ID = sample(11:20),
   Jan = sample(0:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
   Feb = sample(0:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
   Mar = sample(0:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
   Apr = sample(0:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
)
gained.df.ex <- data.frame(example.data$ID)

## customers can't be gained in the first month
## there's no previous data to verify that this is the first time they've been billed, so all values are 0

gained.df.ex$Jan <- rep(0, length(example.data$ID)

## here's the loop that isn't working

for(i in 3:5){
   new.month.dummy <- for (x in 1:length(gained.df.ex$example.data.ID)){
      ifelse(example.data[x,i] == 0, new.month.dummy[x] <- 0, ifelse(sum(example.data[x,2:(i-1)]} == 0, new.month.dummy[x] <-1, new.month.dummy <- 0))
}
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this with apply but I'm not sure how.

The expected output would look as follows:

```
> example.data
   Jan Feb Mar Apr
15   0   3   4   3
19   1   3   0   5
20   4   2   5   1
12   2   1   3   0
14   0   0   2   1
17   5   5   4   4
11   3   4   1   5
18   1   0   0   2
13   3   2   5   3
16   2   5   1   2

> gained.df.ex
   Jan Feb Mar Apr
15   0   1   0   0
19   0   0   0   0
20   0   0   0   0
12   0   0   0   0
14   0   0   1   0
17   0   0   0   0
11   0   0   0   0
18   0   0   0   0
13   0   0   0   0
16   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output based on the example

Comment: do you only have one row per ID?

Comment: expected output has been added to the question.

Comment: Yes, there's only one row per ID

Comment: Why you have all 0s for the second row in expected output?  All the numbers look unique and there is a gain of number 5 after 0.

Comment: In the second row, they had been billed in previous months - they just dropped off for 1 month, so they're not a completely new customer.

Comment: So `Jan` can never be 1... Am I correct?

Comment: Yes - sorry, spacing was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
gained.df.ex[names(example.data)] <- t(apply(example.data, 1, function(x) {
            i1 <- tail(which(cumsum(x)==0),1)
             x1 <- rep(0, length(x))
             if(length(i1) >0) replace(x1, i1+1, 1) else x1}))
gained.df.ex[names(example.data)]
#   Jan Feb Mar Apr
#1    0   1   0   0
#2    0   0   0   0
#3    0   0   0   0
#4    0   0   0   0
#5    0   0   1   0
#6    0   0   0   0
#7    0   0   0   0
#8    0   0   0   0
#9    0   0   0   0
#10   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Still trying to make sense of the original question...but this is a nice method. I was gonna say go with adply and lag and call it a day